# NextJS unable to call from API endpoint

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, axios

I am trying to call from an external API endpoint in NextJS, but I get the error:

```
{"level":50, Wed Jan 24 2024,"pid":4488,"hostname":"DESKTOP-S75IFN7","msg":"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:21:16)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:513:81)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)"}
```

When I try to call from the API endpoint in PostMan, it works. The other API endpoints that I call from have the exact same API (***/register*** and ***/login***), but ***/favourites/add*** and ***/favourites/get-favourites*** don't work.

Here's the code in the NextJS API route:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { logger } from "@/utils/logger"
import axios from 'axios'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

const baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/favourites'

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest, route: { params: { userID: number }}) => {
    console.log('Request Method: ', req.method)
    console.log('Params: ', route.params.userID)
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        try {
            const userID = route.params.userID
            const { data } = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/get-favourites?user_id${userID}`)
            
            if (data != null) {
                return NextResponse.json({
                    result: data,
                    success: true
                })
            } else {
                return new NextResponse('Failed to get favourites', {
                    status: 400
                })
            }
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof Error) {
                logger.error(`${e.stack}`)
                return new NextResponse('Internal Server Error', {
                    status: 500
                })
            }
        }
    } else {
        return new NextResponse('Not Implemented', {
            status: 405
        })
    }
}
```

This is the error i get in the browser's console:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates a [status code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). In your case, this is likely caused by incorrect data being sent to the API endpoint.

You forgot to add a `=` in your URL after `user_id`:

```
/get-favourites?user_id=${userID}`
```